# Xcode error : mdynamic-no-pic

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I am able to compile my XCode project but its giving me this warning -

**PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in .Literal_0 from /Users/ashishagarwal/Downloads/opentok-OpenTok-iOS-Hello-World-739d62d/Opentok.framework/Opentok(h264idct_neon.o). To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie**

How do I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late for this, but I was just looking for an answer to this myself and came across a post that answers it.

Basically in Xcode under the build settings change "Dont create position independent executables" from NO to YES. It has worked for me so far.

Here is the link to the original post as well.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/397946/pie-disabled-absolute-addressing-error.html